Why is Young's modulus represented as a single value in DFT calculations?
In DFT-based calculations, properties like the bulk modulus are logically reported as a single value since they represent isotropic resistance. However, Young's modulus (E) reflects the stress-strain relationship along specific directions, which should vary in anisotropic materials with different lattice constants along a, b, and c.
Why is E typically reported as a single value in these calculations?
Is this due to isotropic assumptions, even for anisotropic materials?
I would appreciate clarification on the assumptions behind this simplification and suggestions for analyzing directional properties.
Thank you!

If you perform an elasticity calculation in DFT, you typically calculate stresses in a series of strained cells, and fit the elastic constants against these stress-strain relations. The lower the symmetry of the crystal, the more unique $C_{ij}$ coefficients it has.
The stiffness matrix in principle encodes the full elastic response of the crystal, in all possible directions. Indeed, compressibility, Young's modulus, or shear can be highly anisotropic. One simple tool to visualize such response is Elate.
In order to have a simpler representation of elastic response across different materials, different averaging schemes exist. Of these, the Voigt average represent the limit of uniform strain, and the Reuss average that of uniform stress. The former represents an upper bound for such properties, the latter a lower bound.

Thank you for your kind answer!
